# How to add different values to an arraylist?

Tags: java

I have a method that randomly selects objects from an arraylist. Those objects are being added to another arraylist I created. How can I make it so that the same object is not added twice?

Let's say I have an arraylist:

**["Chicken", "Dinner", "Noodles"]**

I have another arraylist that I want to add values randomly from the first arraylist:

**[]**

So I use:

`Math.random` to get values from 0-2 and add them to the new arraylist.

Let's name the empty one list2 and the top one firstlist

So:
Assuming integer i is a random number 0-2.

```
list2.add(firstlist.get(i));
```

Yet this has a chance to add the same value, how can I check through list2, to make sure it hasn't been added yet, so I can not add it and pick another value?

Comment: This question is way too broad as it stands. What have you tried? Can you post some code?

Comment: override equals and hashcode in your class and use a Set implementation for your objects.

Comment: The wording of the question is unclear; but I am not convinced OP is asking about avoiding adding duplicate *values*, but rather avoiding picking the same element of the list twice (as in: picking N random items without duplication). Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the other list with a [java.util.Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). If your objects have correct `hashCode()` and `equals()` then they won't be added twice. In other words, use the right collection type for the job.